# Left Join em LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda, wcf

Tenho a representação de 2 classes.

**1ª classe:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PessoaDados
    {
        private Nullable<int> id;
        private string tipo;
        private string razao_social;
        private string nome_fantasia;
        private string cpf_cnpj;
        private string rg_insc_estadual;
        private string insc_substituicao;
        private string insc_municipal;
        private DateTime? data_expedicao_rg;
        private string orgao_expedidor_rg;

        [DataMember]
        public int? Id { get => id; set => id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Tipo { get => tipo; set => tipo = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Razao_social { get => razao_social; set => razao_social = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Nome_fantasia { get => nome_fantasia; set => nome_fantasia = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Cpf_cnpj { get => cpf_cnpj; set => cpf_cnpj = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Rg_insc_estadual { get => rg_insc_estadual; set => rg_insc_estadual = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Insc_substituicao { get => insc_substituicao; set => insc_substituicao = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Insc_municipal { get => insc_municipal; set => insc_municipal = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? Data_expedicao_rg { get => data_expedicao_rg; set => data_expedicao_rg = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Orgao_expedidor_rg { get => orgao_expedidor_rg; set => orgao_expedidor_rg = value; }

    }
}
```

**2ª classe**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Pessoa_enderecoDados
    {
        private Nullable<int> id;
        private int pessoa_id;
        private string logradouro;
        private int numero;
        private string complemento;
        private string ponto_referencia;
        private string cep;
        private string bairro;
        private int cidade_id;
        private string nome_contato;
        private string telefone_1;
        private string ramal_telefone_1;
        private string telefone_2;
        private string ramal_telefone_2;
        private string celular;
        private string email;

        [DataMember]
        public int? Id { get => id; set => id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Pessoa_id { get => pessoa_id; set => pessoa_id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Logradouro { get => logradouro; set => logradouro = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Numero { get => numero; set => numero = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Complemento { get => complemento; set => complemento = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Ponto_referencia { get => ponto_referencia; set => ponto_referencia = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Cep { get => cep; set => cep = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Bairro { get => bairro; set => bairro = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Cidade_id { get => cidade_id; set => cidade_id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Nome_contato { get => nome_contato; set => nome_contato = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Telefone_1 { get => telefone_1; set => telefone_1 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Ramal_telefone_1 { get => ramal_telefone_1; set => ramal_telefone_1 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Telefone_2 { get => telefone_2; set => telefone_2 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Ramal_telefone_2 { get => ramal_telefone_2; set => ramal_telefone_2 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Celular { get => celular; set => celular = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
    }

}
```

Preciso fazer um *Join* de **pessoa** com **pessoa_endereco** usando *LINQ*. Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira mas não ainda não está funcionando:

```
 public IList<PessoaDados> Select()
    {
        takeeatEntities context = new takeeatEntities();
        IList<PessoaDados> listaPessoasEntity = new List<PessoaDados>();



        IList<pessoa> pessoas = (from p in context.pessoa
                                   join e in context.pessoa_endereco on e.pessoa_id equals p.id ed
                                 from d in ed.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   select new { * });

        PessoaDados pessoa_dados = null;
        foreach (pessoa Pessoa in pessoas)
        {
            pessoa_dados = new PessoaDados();
            pessoa_dados.Tipo = Pessoa.tipo;
            pessoa_dados.Razao_social = Pessoa.razao_social;
            pessoa_dados.Nome_fantasia = Pessoa.nome_fantasia;
            pessoa_dados.Cpf_cnpj = Pessoa.cpf_cnpj;
            pessoa_dados.Rg_insc_estadual = Pessoa.rg_insc_estadual;
            pessoa_dados.Insc_substituicao = Pessoa.insc_substituicao;
            pessoa_dados.Insc_municipal = Pessoa.insc_municipal;
            pessoa_dados.Data_expedicao_rg = Pessoa.data_expedicao_rg;
            pessoa_dados.Orgao_expedidor_rg = Pessoa.orgao_expedidor_rg;

            listaPessoasEntity.Add(pessoa_dados);
        }

        return listaPessoasEntity;
    }
```

Ainda sou iniciante em *LINQ*, *Lambda*.
Abaixo segue a imagem do erro, que não chega nem a compilar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PessoaDados
    {
        private Nullable<int> id;
        private string tipo;
        private string razao_social;
        private string nome_fantasia;
        private string cpf_cnpj;
        private string rg_insc_estadual;
        private string insc_substituicao;
        private string insc_municipal;
        private DateTime? data_expedicao_rg;
        private string orgao_expedidor_rg;

        [DataMember]
        public int? Id { get => id; set => id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Tipo { get => tipo; set => tipo = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Razao_social { get => razao_social; set => razao_social = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Nome_fantasia { get => nome_fantasia; set => nome_fantasia = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Cpf_cnpj { get => cpf_cnpj; set => cpf_cnpj = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Rg_insc_estadual { get => rg_insc_estadual; set => rg_insc_estadual = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Insc_substituicao { get => insc_substituicao; set => insc_substituicao = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Insc_municipal { get => insc_municipal; set => insc_municipal = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? Data_expedicao_rg { get => data_expedicao_rg; set => data_expedicao_rg = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Orgao_expedidor_rg { get => orgao_expedidor_rg; set => orgao_expedidor_rg = value; }

        public virtual Pessoa_enderecoDados pessoa_enderecoDados { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Pessoa_enderecoDados
    {
        private Nullable<int> id;
        private int pessoa_id;
        private string logradouro;
        private int numero;
        private string complemento;
        private string ponto_referencia;
        private string cep;
        private string bairro;
        private int cidade_id;
        private string nome_contato;
        private string telefone_1;
        private string ramal_telefone_1;
        private string telefone_2;
        private string ramal_telefone_2;
        private string celular;
        private string email;

        [DataMember]
        public int? Id { get => id; set => id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Pessoa_id { get => pessoa_id; set => pessoa_id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Logradouro { get => logradouro; set => logradouro = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Numero { get => numero; set => numero = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Complemento { get => complemento; set => complemento = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Ponto_referencia { get => ponto_referencia; set => ponto_referencia = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Cep { get => cep; set => cep = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Bairro { get => bairro; set => bairro = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Cidade_id { get => cidade_id; set => cidade_id = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Nome_contato { get => nome_contato; set => nome_contato = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Telefone_1 { get => telefone_1; set => telefone_1 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Ramal_telefone_1 { get => ramal_telefone_1; set => ramal_telefone_1 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Telefone_2 { get => telefone_2; set => telefone_2 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Ramal_telefone_2 { get => ramal_telefone_2; set => ramal_telefone_2 = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Celular { get => celular; set => celular = value; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
    }
}
```

consulta linq:

```
 public IList<PessoaDados> Select()
        {
            takeeatEntities context = new takeeatEntities();
            IList<PessoaDados> listaPessoasEntity = new List<PessoaDados>();

            var pessoas = context.pessoa
                         .GroupJoin(context.pessoa_endereco, p => p.id, a => a.pessoa_id, (p, a) => new { p, a })
                         .SelectMany(a => a.a.DefaultIfEmpty(), (p, a) => new PessoaDados
                         {
                             Id = p.p.id,
                             Razao_social = p.a.razao_social
                         })
                         .ToList();


            PessoaDados pessoa_dados = null;
            foreach (pessoa Pessoa in pessoas)
            {
                pessoa_dados = new PessoaDados();
                pessoa_dados.Tipo = Pessoa.tipo;
                pessoa_dados.Razao_social = Pessoa.razao_social;
                pessoa_dados.Nome_fantasia = Pessoa.nome_fantasia;
                pessoa_dados.Cpf_cnpj = Pessoa.cpf_cnpj;
                pessoa_dados.Rg_insc_estadual = Pessoa.rg_insc_estadual;
                pessoa_dados.Insc_substituicao = Pessoa.insc_substituicao;
                pessoa_dados.Insc_municipal = Pessoa.insc_municipal;
                pessoa_dados.Data_expedicao_rg = Pessoa.data_expedicao_rg;
                pessoa_dados.Orgao_expedidor_rg = Pessoa.orgao_expedidor_rg;
                pessoa_dados.

                listaPessoasEntity.Add(pessoa_dados);
            }

            return listaPessoasEntity;
        }
```

Comment: Qual é o erro obtido?

Comment: Você está usando `Entity Framework` para carga de dados? As Entidades estão relacionadas?

Comment: coloquei uma imagem com o erro, sim é entity framework. model.edmx com as tabelas carregadas. elas tem relacionamentos entre si, a minha intenção é selecionar e alimentar essas 2 classes, ou uni-las, só nao tenho ideia de como faço isso, adicionei uma imagem do erro

Comment: No caso existe `pessoa` que não tem `pessoa_endereco` e você quer trazer todas as pessoa?

Comment: isso mesmo, preciso assim

Comment: @InteliderSistemas pelo o que entendi, está montando uma `DTO` e marcando com `DataContract`, está à enviar estes dados para um serviço  `WCF` ou à monta uma `ViewModel` para o `MVC`?

Comment: estou enviando para um WCF, quando faço com apenas uma tabela funciona ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente gostaria de entrar no merito da longividade do WCF.: [`WCF Is Dead and Web API Is Dying – Long Live MVC 6!`](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/06/wcf-is-dead-long-live-mvc-6/)

Então se estiver à fazer um sistema novo utilizando uma arquitetura `SOA` ou de `Microservices`, aconselho fortimente que utilize `ASP.NET WebAPI` e abuse do `REST`.

Agora vamos discutir um pouco sobre as suas `DTO (Data Transfer Object)`, elas fazem sentido quando o formato dos dados obtidos no banco estão em um formato diferente do que é exporto pela `API` (seja `SOAP/WCF` ou `REST/WebAPI`). 
No seu caso, você está apenas transformando a sua entidade em uma classe com a mesma estrutura, ao meu ver este tipo de mapeamento é desnecessário.

Sim, eu sei que o `WCF` tem problemas com propriedades virtuais, e a `WebAPI` de uma certa forma também o tem.
Neste caso eu aconselho que você altere o `LazyLoadingEnabled` e `ProxyCreationEnabled` para `false` e remova os `virtual` das suas propriedades de navegação.
Ao fazer isto, você estará abrindo mão do `LazyLoad`, mas um `EagerLoad` bem planejado tem um impacto positivo no desempenho da aplicação.

No seu lugar, a primeira coisa que eu faria é abandonar o `EDMX/Database First` e adotar o `Code First`, você pode criar todos as entidades inicias apartir do seu `Banco de Dados` já existente.

- [`Entity Framework Code First Migrations with an existing database`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [`Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx)

As classes que irá obter terá o mesmo nome que está no `Banco de Dados`, aconselho que altere elas para ficarem dentro dos padrões do `C#`

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[Table(Name = 'pessoa')]
public class PessoaDados
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key, Column(Name = "id")]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "tipo")]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "razao_social")]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "nome_fantasia")]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "cpf_cnpj")]
    public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "rg_insc_estadual")]
    public string RgInscEstadual { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "insc_substituicao")]
    public string InscSubstituicao { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "insc_municipal")]
    public string InscMunicipal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "data_expedicao_rg")]
    public DateTime? DataExpedicaoRg { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "orgao_expedidor_rg")]
    public string Orgao_expedidor_rg { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[Table(Name = 'pessoa_endereco')]
public class Endereco
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key, Column(Name = "id")]
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "pessoa_id")]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "logradouro")]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "numero")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "complemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "ponto_referencia")]
    public string PontoReferencia { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(cep)]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "bairro")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "cidadeId")]
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "nome_contato")]
    public string NomeContato { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "telefone_1")]
    public string Telefone1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "ramal_telefone_1")]
    public string RamalTelefone1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "telefone_2")]
    public string Telefone2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(ramal_telefone_2)]
    public string RamalTelefone2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "celular")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(Name = "email")]
    public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }

    [DataMember]
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Uma vez feito isto, o método do seu serviço pode ser simplesmente assim.:

```
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> GetPessoas(string tipo)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        return await db.Pessoas
            .Include(x => x.Enderecos)
            .Where(x => x.Tipo == tipo)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Claro, se o seu contrato expõe apenas parte das suas entidades, então faz sentido ter uma `DTO`, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class PessoaDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? EnderecoId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public EnderecoDTO Endereco { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ContatoDTO Contato { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class EnderecoDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PontoReferencia { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column(cep)]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ContatoDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }     
}
```

A sua operação ficaria assim.:

```
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> GetPessoasResumo(string tipo)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        return await db.Pessoas
            .Include(x => x.Enderecos)
            .Where(x => x.Tipo == tipo)
            .Select(x => new PessoaDTO {
                PessoaId = x.PessoaId,
                Tipo = x.Tipo,
                RazaoSocial = x.RazaoSocial,
                CpfCnpj = x.CpfCnpj,
                EnderecoId = x.Endereco.Any() ? x.Endereco.FirstOrDefault().EnderecoId,
                Endereco = x.Endereco.Any() ? x.Endereco.Select(y => new EnderecoDTO {
                    Logradouro = y.EnderecoId,
                    Numero = y.EnderecoId,
                    Complemento = y.EnderecoId,
                    PontoReferencia = y.EnderecoId,
                    Cep = y.EnderecoId,
                    Bairro = y.EnderecoId,
                    CidadeId = y.EnderecoId,
                }).FirstOrDefault() : default(EnderecoDTO),
                Contato = x.Endereco.Any() ? x.Endereco.Select(y => new ContatoTO {
                    Telefone = y.Telefone,
                    Celular = y.Celular,
                    Email = y.Email
                }).FirstOrDefault() : default(ContatoTO),
            }).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: pessoa vem do mapeamento do edmx, ou seja, é a tabela do banco de dados, enquanto pessoa_dados é a classe que fiz para representa-lo, a minha ideia, é fazer o select join das 2 tabelas e jogar dentro dessa classe que criei, que alias esta faltando os campos do endereço.

Comment: obrigado pela grande atenção e detalhamento do caso, vou ler um pouco para alterar, porém fiquei um pouco triste, vou explicar porque. Tinha o webservice rodando e funcional em asmx, porem como estou reescrevendo o app, usando agora cordova para ser multiplataforma, pensei em reescrever o webservice, li varios artigos falando que o asmx era um legado e que deveria usar wcf ou webapi, das duas optei pelo wcf, porem agora vc diz que ele morreu e o webapi esta morrendo, na sua opinião teria algo melhor que o webapi, que me desse mais longevidade nessa parte do sistema?

Comment: @InteliderSistemas o `WCF` está praticamente morto, especialmente com a popularização dos `Microserviços`, agora quanto á `ASP.NET WebAPI`, dizer que ela morreu, é apenas um `bait click`, na realidade houve uma unificação do `ASP.NET WebAPI` e do `ASP.NET MVC` no `MVC 5`, no `MVC 6` tivemos mais algumas alterações, então o correto seria dizer "A WebAPI antiga morreu, vida longa à nova". Então pode escrever uma `REST API` usando o `MVC 5 ou 6` sem medo de ser feliz.

Comment: Obrigado tobias pela ajuda!.

Comment: depois de ler o artigo que você me indicou no começo do post realmente vou usar o webapi mv6, obrigado!